# Inviting my fiance and Family members to the US when I am on a Study permit

Tags: visas, usa, study

Suppose I move to the USA on F-1 Visa , How can I invite my girlfriend (whom I want to marry) and other family member? Is there a way to invite her or any of my family members to come to the US on F-1 Study permit, or do we have to wait for an adjustment of status, before I can have to invite her or any family member over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On F1 visa you can have your immediate family (spouse and minor dependent children) accompany you. You do not have a privilege to "invite" anyone. They may be able to come to the US on their own accord based on their own eligibility, but your "invitation" doesn't mean much in that regard.

Comment: Really, so on the document , i can put their names and passport numbers and they will also have to give them visas as well (since they accompany me), is that what you mean?

Comment: @CleverTammy No, the answer means the exact opposite. A girlfriend is not classed as a spouse. The only way your girlfriend can go to the US is if she herself is eligible to visit either with an ESTA or by applying for a visa herself.

Comment: @Traveller, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @CleverTammy as Traveller said - spouse is someone you're legally married to. Dependent children are someone whom you're legally a parent/guardian to. "Girlfriend" and "other family member" are complete strangers to you as far as the US government is concerned.